# Navigate To Local Kendo View Programmatically Not Working

Tags: javascript, mvvm, telerik, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

Within kendoUI mobile project, I'm using the latest kendo.all.min.js file (2013.1.319) with JQuery 1.9.1 as described in the documentation to do.  In my one view model, I'm trying to show the second view, but it fails with:

> TypeError: l is null

I have 2 views that look like:

```
<div id="MainView" data-title="My Group List" data-role="view" 
   data-model="listModel" data-layout="StandardLayout">
   .
   .
</div>

<div id="SelectedView" data-title="View Group" data-role="view" 
  data-model="selectedModel" data-layout="StandardLayout">
   .
   .
</div>
```

In the model for the first view, I have this:

```
var listModel = kendo.observable({

    groups: [],

    viewGroup: function (e) {
        selectedModel.set("group", e.data);

                //kendoMobileApp variable pointing to a
                //kendo.mobile.Application object
        kendoMobileApp.navigate("#SelectedView"); /* ERROR HERE */
    }
```

Where I list the error above, I get the TypeError l is null error.  Any idea why?  Is my syntax off?  This has been frustrating trying to debug with a minified script, as a debug version doesn't exist that I know of.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Brian

Make sure you maintain 'kendoMobileApp' variable as global.

Html:

```
<div id="MainView" data-title="My Group List" data-role="view" 
   data-model="listModel" >
       <div>Main View</div>
       <div><a data-role="button" data-bind="click: navigateToSelected">Go to Selected view</a></div>
</div>

<div id="SelectedView" data-title="View Group" data-role="view" 
  data-model="selectedModel">   
      <div>Selected View</div>
       <div><a data-role="button" data-bind="click: navigateToMain">Go to Main view</a></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var listModel =  kendo.observable({
    navigateToSelected: function(){
        kendoMobileApp.navigate('#SelectedView');
    }

});
var selectedModel =  kendo.observable({
    navigateToMain: function(){
        kendoMobileApp.navigate('#MainView');
    }
});

var kendoMobileApp = new kendo.mobile.Application();
```

See the simple example for navigation from [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S7edM/47/).  **Note:** I didn't use a layout, because that is not important here.

Comment: this works. But only once. After navigating back to the main view, it stops working

Comment: Its working well in jsFiddle. did u see that.? it will navigate all the time if you use properly. if you have any queries then post you code here.